# TSQL RegEx Like operator

Tags: sql-server, regex, t-sql

I need to search a varchar(max) field for a particular string pattern. The patter is `aa-aaa-0000000000-0` where the `a` could be any character A-Z and the 0 could be any number 0-9.The dashes are part of the pattern.

I've tried quite a few things so far, but I can't quite get it. I'm currently at this, but it doesn't return any results.

```
select * 
from MyTable 
where Field 
    like '%[A-Z][A-Z][-][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][-][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][-][0-9]%'
```

Comment: Probably because `0000000000` are 10 digits, but `[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]` is for 9 digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix your pattern:

- Change `[A-Z]` to `[a-Z]` (of course it depends on the collation of the `Field` column)
- Add an additional wildcard `[0-9]` to match all 10 characters in the example.

T-SQl:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (VALUES ('aa-aaa-0000000000-0')) v (Field)
WHERE Field LIKE '%[a-Z][a-Z][-][a-Z][a-Z][a-Z][-][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][-][0-9]%'
```

Comment: doh! You're exactly right, I needed an extra `[0-9]` I had mis counted those. I was pulling my brains out why that wasn't working. Also fwiw, the `[A-Z] `or `[a-z] ` is the same. We're not using case sensitive collation

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE (Val VARCHAR(max))
INSERT @T (
                Val
            )
VALUES ( 'aa-aaa-0000000000-0' )

select  * 
from    @T AS T 
where   T.Val like '[A-Z][A-Z][-][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][-][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][-][0-9]'
```

Just add another [0-9] to make 10 digits

Comment: Probably `[A-Z]` should be `[a-Z]`

Comment: Perhaps, though that depends on collation. I'm on an case insensitive collation, I assumed OP is too, considering their attempt.

Comment: @HoneyBadger You're right.. we're not using a case sensitive collation.

Answer (score 1):

You're just looking for

```
WHERE Column LIKE '%[a-z][a-z]-[a-z][a-z][a-z]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9]%'
```